# "Didn't she say something?" vs. "Didn't she say anything?"

Tags: grammar, interrogatives, conversation, some-vs-any

I think the second statement has negative meanings maybe the speaker thought she didn't even say a single word. Or he/she hesitates between the person speaking or not(speaking), but it's more likely that she's been silence.

1- Didn't she say something?

2- Didn't she say anything?

Answer (score 4):

(1) implies that the speaker expects the answer 'Yes', confirming their belief that she did in fact say something.

(2) implies surprise that she did not speak. "Did she really not say anything at all?"

Comment: Do you think (1) does not express surprise? Do you think that (2) doesn't imply the speaker would normally expect the answer "yes"?

Comment: @gotube - Answer amended. Yes, I think that (2) is asking for confirmation that 'she' indeed said nothing - not quite the same as 'expecting the answer "yes"'.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences mean roughly the same thing. The problem with understanding those questions is that there are two structures there which can express implied expectations of the answer.

Normally, a question with "something" implies the speaker expects the answer "yes", and a question with "anything" implies the speaker doesn't know what to expect.

And normally, *negative questions* like "*Didn't she" + verb?*" mean you'd normally expect her to do the verb, in this case you're asking for confirmation that she did not, because it's so strange.

So whether the speaker uses "something" or "anything", it expresses that they believe a person would normally say something in that situation, but they're asking for confirmation that she in fact didn't say anything.